# I want to make this program looping till the user will input N for No

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckPassFail {
    static char tr;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        do{
            Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
            double mark;
            System.out.println("Enter a random number :");
            mark = x.nextDouble();
            double g = mark%2;
            if(g==0)
                System.out.println("BREAK EVEN");
            else
                System.out.println("PRETTY ODD");
            System.out.println("You want to try another number?\nY = YES and N = NO");
            tr = x.next().charAt(0);
        }
        while(tr == 'Y');
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have an error? You need to give a value to tr in your declaration. static char tr='Y';

Comment: don't put to much information in the title. try to explain your code. show your your input, output and what you expected.

Comment: Your condition should probably be `while(tr != 'N')` to account for user input that isn't Y(ES) or N(O).

Comment: lol i jst figured it out. i jst lacked a "return;" statement after the while. thats why it wont return to main. anyways thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first one: add a toUpperCase() to get rid of lower-case characters (so y is interpreted the same way as Y.

```
tr = x.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
```

The second one: you say you want to loop until there is a N. For that just replace

```
while(tr == 'Y');
```

with

```
while(tr != 'N');
```

Other than that you code seems to do what it should. I tested it and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to do something like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //Instantiate outside of loop.
String str = ""; //Define and initialize before the loop as well to avoid a null pointer exception.

do {
    str = in.next();

} while (str.startsWith("Y"));
```

Also, you should instantiate your Scanner object outside of the loop.  This way you don't unnecessarily re-instantiate a brand new instance every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need the tr variable just go with

```
while(x.next().equals("Y"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `while(tr != 'N');` instead of `while(tr == 'Y');`.